# How do I trigger Form Submission in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, jquery-events

I have initialized my form submission like following:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#my_form").submit(function(e) {
         ...
         ...
   }
}
```

As you see above, it is in `$(document).ready(...)`. When user press "Submit" button on UI, the form will be submitted.

But, How can I also trigger this form submission in Javascript besides user input (e.g. press submit button on UI)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call the [`submit()` <sup>DOCs</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/submit/) method on the form.

```
$("#my_form").submit();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$("#my_form").submit();`

Answer (score 1):

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#SubmitForm").click(function (e) {
            var textContent = $("#TextContent").val();
            textContent = jQuery.trim(textContent);
            if (textContent == "") {
                alert("Content field cannot be empty.");
                $("#TextContent").focus();
                return false;
            }
            else{ $("#my_form").submit();
            }
        });
    });
```